# execute a powershell script with parameters from cmd

Tags: powershell, cmd

I have a powershell scripts that accepts these parameters

```
param(
[parameter(Mandatory = $false,Position = 0)][string] $Install    = $false,
[parameter(Mandatory = $false,Position = 1)][string] $Silent     = $false,
[parameter(Mandatory = $false,Position = 2)][string]$ConfigFile  = ".\TESTproc.json"                
)
```

If i start the script using powershell by calling:

```
J:\Script\TESTProc.ps1 $true $true
```

the first two parameters install and silent are set to true, just like want it to be.

But I have to execute this PS Script using cmd for some reasons and doing this with this line:

```
powershell -Command "& 'J:\Script\TESTProc.ps1' '$true' ‘$true'"
```

If i start the script like this, $true can't be assigned to the two parameters.

How can I assign $true to the two parameters using cmd.

Comment: Did you try _not_ single-quoting the arguments? `powershell -Command "& 'J:\Script\TESTProc.ps1' $true $true"`

Comment: Yeah, just tried it and got it. Thx for the answer tho.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen however, i can't explain myself, why single quote isn't working here. Can u explain it to me?

Comment: I'm confused, did my suggestion solve your problem or not?

Comment: it helped. Sorry for the confusion. My question, i am not sure, why using single-quote doesn't work ?

Comment: Well, single-quotes create a _string_ value, but it'll be the literal value `$true`, not `True` - so if later in the script you pass those arguments to an executable or command that expects the string `true`, it breaks.

Comment: ok..Thx for the explanation